# IF statement in Jenkins windows boolean parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

On Jenkins installed on windows 7, I choose :

This build is parameterized

Add a Boolean parameter named WIN7

Then in Windows batch command I want to do something if WIN7 parameter is selected.

How boolean are converted? I tried the following but no success

```
IF %WIN7%=="true" (

)
```

Also :

```
echo %WIN7%
```

is printing true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IF "%WIN7%"=="true" (
...
)
```

Quotes are also part of the compared string.And are required when there is a space within the compared values.